# hide form using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Javascript:

```
function next(a)
{
    if(a==1)
    {
        document.getElementById("form1").style.display="none";
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<form onsubmit="next(1)" action="add.php" method="post" id="form1">
    <center>Add New Survey</center>
     <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p align="left"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Title:    </p>
    <textarea name="title" cols="2" class="inputs" id="title"></textarea>
    <p align="left"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Discription: (Optional)    </p>
    <textarea name="dis" cols="2" class="inputs" id="dis"></textarea>
     <p align="left"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Number of questions:    </p>


          <input type="Submit" value="Next" class="button" name="b1"/>
      </p>
  </form>
```

Here is my code. When I submit the form, it concealed the form for a few seconds and then again it showed up. I want to hide it until another button is pressed where another javascript function is called to show the form. Please help me. I am new to Javascript.

Comment: Take a look at jQuery `.show()` and `.hide()`

Comment: Also, it's `Description` not `Discription` ;-)

Comment: Inline JavaScript is something you shouldn't be doing? I suggest that you spend some time on reading about JavaScript/jQuery and CSS. You will thank me later when you need to do maintenance on your code! ;) PS: People will probably downvote your question because your code is not complying to any current coding standards.

Comment: I know it is not answer to your question, but please go and learn each technique (HTML, CSS, JavaScript) separatly from a quality source in that order otherwise you will teach yourself bad coding style that is hard to unlearn. Good luck!!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `return false`

```
<form onsubmit="return next(1)" action="add.php" method="post" id="form1">
```

Then

```
function next(a)
{
  if(a==1){
    document.getElementById("form1").style.display="none";
    return false;
  }
}
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/muralim/4q7QU/5/)

**UPDATE:** To Show the form

```
<input type="Submit" value="Show" class="button"  
 onclick="return showForm()" name="show"/>



function showForm()
{
    document.getElementById("form1").style.display="block";
    return false;
}
```

Comment: And if you return false the form is not submitted

Comment: Sounds to me like he doesn't want to submit the form - just hide it for now.

Comment: @mplungjan, I think OP don't want to submit the form based on some validation conditions.

Answer (score -1):

If you want the form to submit and are not plann9ing to use AJAX, you need the PHP to do the hiding when reloading the page

```
if(isset($_POST['b1']))  { // name of your submit button
  $hide = true;
 ?>
 <input type="button" id="button1 value="click to show form again" />
<? } ?>

  <form id="form1" class="<? echo $hide?"hidden":"shown";?>"></form>
```

and add

```
$(function() {
  $("#button1").on("click",function() {
    $("#form1").prop("class","shown");
  });
});
```

plus a css

```
.hidden { display:none }
.shown { display:block }
```

Comment: No they don't - but I will with a quote from the question : _"I want to hide it until another button is pressed where another javascript function is called to show the form."_

Comment: Ah, that does not mean that the form is not submitted, but that a button is shown. I will change the script

Comment: It does mean it's not submitted.  If it is submitted then the page reloads (or redirects).

Comment: Sorry, but he's clearly asking for a client-side solution.  This is way overkill.

Comment: Unless he wants to use Ajax, he clearly needs to submit the form. He also complains that the form hides for a second and then shows again, which means he is reloading the page add.php.

Comment: Yes, exactly.  Submitting the form is the problem.  See the selected answer.