# I would like to hide a form and display and image based on the country dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to hide a form and display a contact us button based on the country dropdown.  So if the user selects US it shows the whole form.  If the user selects CA the form disappears and shows a contact us message.

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
       $("#bill_contry").change(function () {
             var country = this.value;
             if(country == "US"){
               $("#bank_name").html("Bank Name");
                $("#routing_number").html("Routing Number (9 digits)");

            $("#qty1").html("1 - $349 USD each");
            $("#qty2").html("2 - $339 USD each");
            $("#qty3").html("3 - $329 USD each");

            $( "#help_image1" ).attr("href", "images/CheckAcctRoutingNumHelp.jpg");

            $( "#help_image2" ).attr("href", "images/CheckAcctRoutingNumHelp.jpg");

            $( "#help_image3" ).attr("href", "images/CheckAcctRoutingNumHelp.jpg");

        } else if(country == "CA"){
            $("#bank_name").html("Bank Number ( 3 digits )");
            $("#routing_number").html("Transit# ( 5-6 digits )");    

            $("#qty1").html("1 - $374 CAD each");
            $("#qty2").html("2 - $364 CAD each");
            $("#qty3").html("3 - $354 CAD each");

            $( "#help_image1" ).attr("href", "images/cad_cheque.jpg");

            $( "#help_image2" ).attr("href", "images/cad_cheque.jpg");

            $( "#help_image3" ).attr("href", "images/cad_cheque.jpg");

        }

    });
```

Form

```
<form action="process_order.php" method="post" name="form1">
```

### #1Select your country

```
<select name="bill_country" id="bill_contry">
    <option value="US">USA</option>
    <option value="CA">CA</option>
</select>       

 <h2><span>#2</span> Select your number of </h2>
     <select name="qty">
     <option id="qty1" value="1">1 - $349 USD each</option>
     <option id="qty2" value="2">2 - $339 USD each</option>
     <option id="qty3" value="3">3 - $329 USD each</option>
```

Comment: so what seems to be the problem?

Comment: I Dont know how to hide the  form and display a message if the user selects canada from the drop down.

Comment: there's no form name here or elements (like the drop-down box or any Submit or other buttons), so it's not possible to answer at the moment. Are you sure you want to hide the whole form including the CA option they just clicked? It might be better to hide all the unwanted elements in the form, and add a message instead. This answer contains useful code to hide a form http://stackoverflow.com/a/23563942/4258817

Comment: Hi @Mousey thanks for the response.  you are correct I would prefer to leave the ca selection and just have a contact us or something of that nature.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is put two forms on your page for USA and CA and then simply hide and show when a value has been selected from the select options.

Here is my jsFiddle example

jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/1q633sp3/

HTML

```
<select class="country">
    <option>USA</option>
    <option>CA</option>
</select>
<form id="default-form">
    <p>Form properties go here</p>
    <select name="qty">
        <option id="qty1" value="1">1 - $349 USD each</option>
        <option id="qty2" value="2">2 - $339 USD each</option>
        <option id="qty3" value="3">3 - $329 USD each</option>
    </select>
    <button type="button">Submit</button>
</form>
<form id="contact-us">
    <p>Please get in contact with us</p>
    <textarea name="message"></textarea>
    <button type="button">Submit</button>
</form>
```

jQuery

```
$(function () {
    $('#contact-us').hide();

    $('.country').on('change', function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "CA") {
            $('#default-form').slideUp();
            $('#contact-us').slideDown();
        } else if ($(this).val() == "USA") {
            $('#default-form').slideDown();
            $('#contact-us').slideUp();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I ended up using a redirect which I know is frowned upon but thanks for the answers